# Random walk on a Penrose tiling

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, random-walks, tiling

Pólya proved that a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ almost surely returns to the
origin, or, equivalently, returns to the origin infinitely often.
It was subsequently established that in $\mathbb{Z}^3$, a random walk returns
to the origin with probability about 34%.

My question is:

> **Q**. What is the probability that a random walk on the edges of a
>   [Penrose tiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling) returns to its starting point?

Each step from a vertex of the tiling follows one of the incident edges chosen randomly.

---

[image: Penrose Tiling]

 
 
 
 
 
<sub>(Image from [this link](http://plus.maths.org/content/trouble-five))</sub>

---

I am wondering to what extent this aperiodic but "quasiregular" tiling
mimics the $\mathbb{Z}^d$ lattice from the viewpoint of random walks.

One could ask the same question of a notion of 3D Penrose tiles, e.g.,

> Dietl, Ruth Maria Katharina, and Jost-Hinrich Eschenburg. "Three-Dimensional Penrose Tilings and Self-Similarity."
>   ([PDF download link](http://www.math.uni-augsburg.de/~eschenbu/Penrose3D.pdf))
>   
>    
>    
>    
>    
>    
>   [image: 3D Penrose Tiling]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Presumably (though I don't have references handy) the behaviour of a quasiregular tiling in ${\mathbb Z}^d$ is essentially the same as that of ${\mathbb Z}^d$ itself.  Essentially this should depend on the fact that the number of sites within  $r$ steps of your starting point grows as $r^d$.

Comment: Thanks, Robert, especially for the high-level viewpoint, which makes my potentially complex question actually quite simple. So you cut through the complexity to the essence!